# Duplicate identifier 'test'

Tags: typescript, testing, node-modules, tsc

```
function test(){
    return 1;
}
```

Why do such test cases report duplicate definitions when using tsc conversion, as follows
**
node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2620:13 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'test'.

2620 declare var test: Mocha.TestFunction;
~~~~

test2.ts:1:10
1 function test(){
~~~~
'test' was also declared here.

test2.ts:1:10 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'test'.

1 function test(){
~~~~

node_modules/@types/mocha/index.d.ts:2620:13
2620 declare var test: Mocha.TestFunction;
~~~~
'test' was also declared here.

Found 2 errors.
**

Comment: Can you add the actual test "describe" declaration of the test, also? Otherwise it is hard to tell what is going on.